# Problems with bootstrap popover z-index

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get z-index work on bootstrap popover if it's in div which has [smooth div scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) on it. I've tried putting extremely high values, looked in all css's to see if there were any z-indexes higher then popover's but achieved no success.

Javascript:

```
$(".project").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    hotSpotScrolling: false,
    touchScrolling: true
});
$(".block").popover({
    html: true,
    animation: true,
    placement: 'right'
});
```

Here's how it looks at the moment: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Fw2.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLnDs.png).

Live example: [here](http://emmorts.lhosting.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipping you are seeing is probably not related to z-index declarations but instead related to the size of your `.project` div and the overflow declaration for a nested div.

```
div.scrollWrapper {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

The `overflow:hidden;` is what's creating the clips you're seeing.

Comment: True, but altering it in any way negates whole scrolling script and still does not show whole popover.

Comment: You are correct, we (myself and jas7457) were just pointing out that this is not a problem that can be solved via z-index.  try adding: "padding-top:20px;" to your "div.scrollWrapper" CSS declaration.  That seemed to do the trick and make the popover visible for me when playing around with it in inspector.  Ultimately you're going to have to add some height to this element to make these popovers visible.

Answer (score 19):

This is old, but for others, try adding the following attribute:

```
data-container="body"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has something to do with your overflow. It seems to be clipping your boxes. If you look at .scrollWrapper in smoothDivScroll.css and change overflow to visible, you will see a bit more of our box. I know this isn't your desired effect, but I think it's a start. Has to be something with your overflow.

Answer (score 1):

@ the mad zergling

I have [an popover](http://www.recuperodati.biz/nas/) that pops automatically on page load and gets hidden automatically after some timeout (in the reality it gets destroyed), it is indicating a brief instruction on/about the navbar itself. I also do use scrollto.

I've tried adding

```
data-container="body"
```

no way, the behaviour is for the mobiles and depends on that mobile device and its browser.

On blackberry OS 10 it behaves as expected, popover is on top of everything and it was not needed the data-container (though it could be helpful for other devices)

On samsung/android the default browser doesn't show the popover, though also some html5 circles are displayed as squares, so looks it is neither html5 capable, also the dropdown items are not fully displayed, a total scrap.
On the same samsung/android, firefox is much more better but there, the popover is hidden by the navbar logo. Not tried chrome for android.

I expect it will be its own story for every mobile browser on each particular device.

Comment: If you're still having this problem maybe make a new question? I ended up not being a big fan of popovers in bootstrap 2, as I kept running into odd and surprising behaviors. often it was easier to just use an absolutely positioned div and a little javascript to show and hide it.